# Error : Message-Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing script to add my ssh key to bitbucket's deployment key using selenium. Untill the line

```
driver.find_element_by_id('add-key').click()
```

works fine but when a pop up comes, and I want to enter the key in the specific field

```
driver.find_element_by_name('key').send_keys('testing key added')
```

It throws this error
**Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**. I searched on google about this. I come to know that firstly I need to go to this popup window, then I will be able to pass values to respective element. I dont know how to do it.

[image]

Please help me how can I focus to the new pop-up window.
I also used time.sleep(10) but still it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Have you checked with put wait or sleep after click on Add Key button?

Comment: Yes, I have used time.sleep(10) but it didn't worked for me

Comment: I have posted one answer please verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `driver.find_element_by_name('key').send_keys('testing key added')` is giving list of elements. So script need to identify unique element of textarea.

Solution : xpath : `(//textarea[@name='key'])[2]`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//textarea[@name='key'])[2]").send_keys('testing key added')`
```

Hope You found solution.

**Note :** If you are getting error randomly , Also Put wait or sleep. This cause minimize the chances of element is not visible(root cause : page is not loaded properly.)

Comment: It throws an error driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@name="key"]')[2].send_keys('key added')
TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//textarea[@name='key'])[2]") use this

Comment: I have one more doubt regarding this. I have <button resolved="" class="aui-button aui-button-primary dialog-submit">Add key </button> but using driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[contains(text(),"Add key")]').click() is not working. Can u please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104177/discussion-between-vivek-puri-and-sagar007).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify the list of windows present, as in your case there are two windows,
 parent and new one child. So move the control to child window by specifying name of child Window.(For Verification weither you are on child window or not 
 add getTitle() Method onces you moved to child window)
as soon as control move on child window, you can enter value for SSH key.(Below code is in java)

```
// get  window ids of all windows 
 Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    
        Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   

        String parentWindow = itererator.next();
        String  childWindow = itererator.next();

        driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
        //Enter the value for ssh key,Save and close the child window.

        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); // now swicth back to the Parent WINDOW.
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Hope this will work for you.. :)

Comment: This seems good but I don't know Java to Python conversion of this code

Answer (score 0):

I think you not needed to focus to that Pop-up window, please use the Xpath method (find_element_by_xpath) to point that element.

Comment: Can you please try to get that element by "id" instead of "name". ie;    driver.find_element_by_id('key').send_keys('testing key added')

Comment: I have already tried by id but it requires focus of the element first.